# Unable to install visual studio 2012 on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I was attempting to install Visual Studio 2012 Express Version on windows 7, but got the following error.

[image]

The error talks about some Interop Assem, which I believe is related to Microsoft Office. I tried to install the Interop Assem, but it seems that they cannot be installed for Starter Versions of the Microsoft Office.

So, how do I go about installing Visual Studio 2012 on my Windows 7 machine, without full version of Microsoft Office installed, Or the error is related to something else.

**Update:**

I have tried to install the following

[Interop Assem](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508)

but the installation terminates without any status.

Comment: I would follow the link, look at the logs and find a googleable error.

Comment: The interop assemblies are not (strictly) office related.  They are VS prerequisites (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164686.aspx) and there's an error.  You should look at the log file link shown in your window.

Comment: Shall I post the complete contents of log file here ? @Joe, I had already visited the link you have mentioned. I tried to install that assembly, but the installation starts and terminates without any result.

Comment: Please see the update included in the question

Comment: @Nirvan - The problem is connected to install the .NET Framework 4.5 you need to figure out why its failing.  The log file likely is way to long to post, so extract, the specific error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to install from iso image and getting all kinds of different errors. I am not sure what was wrong, but when I tried to install online, the installation was smooth without any errors. I don't know whether this is an answer to the original question, but since the online installer worked, I would rather close this question.

Please note that Service Pack 1 is a requirement for installing VS2012 on Windows 7

Comment: Well if using the most recent/on-line installer is the solution to this error you can accept your own answer and leave it to help anyone else who runs into the same issue.

Comment: -1 This is not an answer.